# Having problem making a JScrollPane appear

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

So I've been troubleshooting this as much as possible, but I just wanted to create a function that would take in a buffered stream and then display the contents of that buffered stream in a scrollable pane. However every time I've run it the window doesn't show up at all. I'd like to know what I've done wrong here.

```
void show(BufferedOutputStream showFileContent)
    {
        String fileContent = showFileContent.toString();
        JTextArea content = new JTextArea(fileContent);

        JScrollPane scrollableScreen = new JScrollPane(content);
        JPanel makeScreenAppear = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        scrollableScreen.setViewportView(makeScreenAppear);
        scrollableScreen.setVisible(true);
        scrollableScreen.setSize(500,400);
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're asking about why a bug is occurring and posting code, but consider this -- you don't yet know the full cause of the bug yet (else I don't think you'd need to be asking this question in this way), so perhaps you're not even showing the right code. This is one (of the many) reason(s) we ask you to create and post a valid [mcve] with your question. For all we know the error could reside elsewhere.

Comment: Issues I've noticed: where do you add the components above to the GUI? And how do you add them to the GUI (top-level window)? You know its best to add the components to the GUI at program creation and then fill the text components with text as the program as is running. Also, does your code respect Swing threading rules? Impossible for us to tell at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the `JTextArea` with an empty `JPanel` as the viewport of the `JScrollPane` in this line of your code:

```
scrollableScreen.setViewportView(makeScreenAppear);
```

That's why you don't see the text. No need for the `JPanel`. Simple add the `JScrollPane` to the top-level window - which I assume is `JFrame` or `JDialog`.